# Is it possible in Python to play sound/music from website without open the browser?

Tags: python, selenium, audio, browser, playback

I found some solution with Selenium, but Selenium open the browser to play the selected music, so it's not the perfect way for me.

Is it possible to play music from website without open the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the lib `playsound`.

```
import os
import requests
import playsound

url = 'YOUR_URL_HERE'
downloaded_file_location = '/tmp/audiofile.wav'

# Downloading the audio file
r = requests.get(url)
with open(downloaded_file_location, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

# Playing the audio file
playsound.playsound(downloaded_file_location, True)

# Removing the audio file
os.remove(downloaded_file_location)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from requests import get

try:
    from playsound import playsound
except:
    from os import system
    system('pip install playsound')

x = get(music_link).content

file = open('music.mp3','wb')
file.write(x)
file.close()

playsound('music.mp3')
```